# [Octave]Trouble visualising how to write a row vector of exponents

Tags: matlab, octave

as the title states, I was following a guideline on coding a polynomial regression function but I am currently stuck on what it means to write a row vector of exponents. I need to initialise two variables, one being 'vector1', a column vector of a variable 'X', and 'vector2' which is meant to be a row vector of exponents from 1 to 'p'. Once that's done, I'm supposed to fill it in the bsxfun as such "X_poly = bsxfun(@power, vector1, vector2)".

Now the problem arises when I try to write in vector2. I have trouble visualising how to write this code. I've tried "vector2 = X(1:p,:)", "vector2 = X*p", "vector2 = X'(1:p,:)". Obviously none of these worked and I just feel this strong sense of defeat everytime I get it wrong. I've tried googling but the results have yielded no fruition.

I feel very lost and I'm grasping at straws at this point.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with symbolic math or do you know the value of `p` and have values in your `x` vector?

Comment: It's symbolic math, I do not know what the values represent but an example in similar vein would be something like "X is a column vector [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10], increase the power of each value by 1 as you gradually go down the vector (e.g 1^1, 2^2,3^3,4^4)"  (I'm really bad with mathematical terminologies so I apologise if I am not being very efficient with my sentences)

Comment: you really should add a MCVE

Comment: `vector2 = 1:p;`

Comment: @beaker, thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `bsxfun` here, the `power` function (and its equivalent operator `.^`) is vectorised (i.e. it can accept arrays process them in an element-wise manner).

```matlab
octave:1> v1 = 1:10;
octave:2> v2 = 1:10;
octave:3> v1 .^ v2
ans =
    1    4    27    256   3125   46656  8.2354e+05  1.6777e+07  3.8742e+08  1e+10
octave:4> power(v1,v2)
ans =
    1    4    27    256   3125   46656  8.2354e+05  1.6777e+07  3.8742e+08  1e+10
octave:5> bsxfun(@power, v1, v2)
ans =
    1    4    27    256   3125   46656  8.2354e+05  1.6777e+07  3.8742e+08  1e+10
```